# Obter o valor tendo em conta duas colunas

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou a tentar obter a número de licenças anti-vírus por departamento e não consigo criar uma formula que me consiga devolver esta informação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente, quero obter quantas licenças existem no departamento "Compras".

```
=CONTAR.SE(Gestão!B3:B1000; "Compras")
```

Esta formula é para obter o número de computadores no Departamento de Compras. Agora eu quero obter o número de utilizadores, no departamento de compras que tenham licença anti-vírus.

```
=CONTAR.SE(Gestão!B3:B1000; "Compras") + CONTAR.SE(Gestão!H3:H1000; "X")
```

Experimentei esta formúla, mas obviamente não funciona.

O resultado seria que nas Compras existem 2 licenças anti-vírus.

Comment: Seja mais claro na sua pergunta,e forneça mais detalhes,pois da forma que está fica dificil de ajudar.

Comment: Creio que a função CONT.SE possa ajuda-lo. Coloque em D1: `=CONT.SE(A2:A5;"Compras")`

Comment: Já atualizei! Peço desculpa! @KALIBBAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forneça os dados da coluna "H" .Mas creio que desta forma funcione: `=CONT.SES(Gestão!B3:B1000; "Compras";Gestão!H3:H1000; "X")`

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado! Testei à pouco com esta formula e por algum motivo não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Pode resolver com a seguinte fórmula:

`=CONT.SES(Gestão!B3:B1000;"Compras";Gestão!H3:H1000;"<>"&"")`